# Render Partial View to String and Convert to PDF

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, pdf, renderpartial

Is there a way to render my Partial View to String or Html? and used that to convert to PDF?

I guess, the only item I need to accomplish is to Render my Partial View to String or HTML, if it's possible.

I already have a tool that can get .htm/.html files and convert it to PDF.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you response. However, can the result of RenderViewToString can be used to convert it to PDF?

Comment: Looks like it's possible [Spire.PDF for .NET](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Knowledgebase/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/PDF-Conversion/Convert-HTML-String-to-PDF-in-C.html); also [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=html+string+to+pdf+c%23).